# I have Vespa sxl 150 scooter.It behaves strange while giving aceleration

Tags: throttle, scooter, vespa

It may sound funny but i found this  after  several days. While moving towards west  the scooter  works well and easily reaches 100 km/hr. But when moving towards east the scooter  never go above 85 km/hr  in spite of giving full acceleration.

I tried this on different roads and the result seem to be the same.

Can you please suggest me something or give some advice? Please.

Comment: It sounds to me like your scooter is possessed. J/K! Really, no clue unless you're going up hill going east and downhill going west ... only thing I got.